# Making a drawn shape or blitted image stay on screen after mouse click events

Tags: mouseevent

I want to make a drawn shape, like a circle, stay on screen after mouse click but after clicking, the shape that i draw vanishes.

```
pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
if rectangle1.collidepoint(pos):
    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
       pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (300, 300)
```

After executing this, the shape appears after a left click of the mouse but after a let go, it vanishes.

I tried using MOUSEBUTTONDOWN event but still the same results and tried blitting an image instead of drawn shapes.

```
if rectangle1.collidepoint(pos):
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
       if event.button == 1:
           pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (300, 300)
```